# C++ output formatting error

Tags: c++, text, file-io, formatting

I was working on output formatting on C++ when I came across this weird error. Here is a sample of my code used to print info contained in an array:

```
int store;
while(table[i]!=NULL)
            {
                store=table[i]->ReturnID();
                output<<"ID: "<<setw(9)<<store<<"\t"; // Export to a file channel
                store=table[i]->ReturnTotalNumber();
                output<<" Total Number: "<<setw(5)<<store<<endl;
                i++;
            }
```

Although the code compiles and works as intended here is a part of my output.txt file:

```
ID:       243    Total Number:     0
ID:       312 Total Number:     0
ID:       458    Total Number:     0
ID:       700    Total Number:     0
ID:       738    Total Number:     0
.....
```

The second line of the txt file always seems to be off balance. The rest are OK no matter how many they are. I have also noticed that changing the first **setw(9)** from 9 to any other random number fixes that bug but I can't explain it. Anyone have any explanation for this? My compiler is GCC-G++ version 4.4.1 and my IDE is Code::Blocks 10.05.

Comment: Do you have a short example that can reproduce the output?

Comment: instead of \t have u tried just spaces or something else? its the tab thats failing.. for whatever reason

Comment: I am afraid not. This is part of a big project about Inverted Indexes and the code is too much to fit into a short example. Thankfully this doesn't cause any great problem as I am only using the output file for debugging I was curious why is that happening.

Comment: Using spaces or any other number does produce the correct output, I am just curious about why is \t failing :)

Comment: What program are you viewing the output.txt file with?  _Thats_ probably where the problem is.  Different programs render tabs differently.  Open the file in a hex viewer or tell us the size of the file so we can validate that the problem is or is not with the code.

Comment: What's the type of "store"? string, int? And which compiler/version?

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you using a tab?  Don't use tab.  use `setw`

Comment: @MooingDuck The size of the portion of the file you are viewing is 160byes. I have used both notepad and notepad++. Even if it is a program problem why does it render only one tab incorrectly?

@ Chubsdad Sorry I forgot to mention this, gonna add to post now, string is of type *int* and compiler is GCC 4.4.1.

Comment: @MooingDuck: As I said, different programs render tabs differently.  Unfortunately, I don't know of _any_ that would produce that output.  By my math that portion of the file should be either 170 or 175 bytes depending on the OS.  Anyway, 160 is a multiple of 5, so that means the tab _is_ there.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an invisible char, e.g. backspace, after ID 312?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the strings you're outputting, it appears that the tab has somehow gone astray. Your task therefore is to find out whether it's not being *output* by the program or whether it's not being rendered by whatever tool you're using to look at the output.

I would send the output to a file then use whatever hex dump utility you have to examine said file to see if the tab is actually there. Under Linux (or Windows with CygWin), you could use:

```
od -xcb fileNameYouCapturedTo
```

If you can establish it's not being output, raise a bug on `glibc` [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/). If it is being output then you have two possibilities.

First, you can file a bug against whatever tool you're using to view the output, whether that be an editor or the terminal program you're using (since it doesn't appear to be treating tabs correctly).

Or you could ditch the tabs altogether and just output a single space. Given that you're columns are already lined up because of the `setw()`, there's little need for tabs here.